# Team Foundation, deleted csproj file. source control cannot checkin/delete

Tags: tfs

At some stage I created a project under my solution. Checked it in. Then later removed it from the solution and deleted the files manually.

When i go to the check in window, the project is still there:
`Service.csproj | edit | (Folder Location)

Service.csprojvspscc | edit | (Folder Location)`

I cant check them in because they do not exist anymore.

`Check In: Operation not performed

Cound not find file (folder location)

Please refer to the Output window for more information`

The output window basically echos what is said above.

How do i remove these file from listing here? I dont need them in source control or on the local machine anymore.

Comment: try: include them again, check in, exclude from the project and check in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the solution and choose "Undo Pending Changes" - in the window that pops up, select only those files that belonged to the project you deleted.